# Trouble with python regex matching

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I am tying to write a regular expression to match the dates in a string.

> timeStamps = '25-12-2017 25:12:2017 25.12.2017'
>
> pattern = r'(\d{2}(?:-|:|.)){2}\d{4}'
>
> [ re.search(pattern,ts) for ts in timeStamps.split()]

re.search is working without any problem and works exactly the way wanted.

```
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='25-12-2017'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='25:12:2017'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='25.12.2017'>]
```

When i change the re.search to re.findall, The result was different.

```
[ re.findall(pattern,ts) for ts in timeStamps.split()]
[['12-'], ['12:'], ['12.']]
```

**Why the two functions are giving two different output?**

Comment: It's only capturing the first capture group, if that's not what you want, then don't use them

Comment: You have a capture group in the pattern. Make it non capture works `(?:\d{2}(?:-|:|.)){2}\d{4}`

Comment: Thanks all, Problem solved when i change to non capturing group.